# how to see or create the diagram from an existing SSAS cube?

Tags: sql-server, ssas, olap-cube

I am new in SSAS. I am trying to figure out the diagram of the existing cube. Is there any way to see the diagram from the existing SSAS cube? Or can I create the diagram form that existing cube?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you have access to SQL Server Data Tools within Visual Studio, which you can use to create and deploy SSAS solutions with cubes in them, you can always import an existing deployed database back to a project by using the "Import From Server" option in SQL. You can then see a graphical representation of the cubes within that Database.

[image: Import From Server]